# What are the priorities when calling template and non template functions?

Tags: c++, templates

Why does this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T> void f(T t) {cout << "A";}
template <> void f(float x) {cout << "B";}
void f(float x) {cout << "C";}

int main()
{
    float x;
    f(x);
    f<>(x);
    f<float>(x);

    return 0;
}
```

display this: `CBB`  ?

It's very unclear for me especially why `f<float>(x);` displays `B`. Could you tell me some more general rules about the priority of calling template and non template functions with the same name ?

Comment: A non-template oveload is always given higher priority.

Comment: What did you expect to be called for `f<float>(x)`?

Comment: @Evg I thought ```f<float> (x) ``` will call ```template <class T> void f(T t) {cout << "A";}
```.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of specialising the template for type float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Walter E Brown teaches in his [2018 CppCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIDEjY5ywqU) there are levels of priority for templates based on specialization:

- non-template overloads are always picked first; non-templates are more specialized than templates themselves.
- specialized templates (your `template <> void f(float)`); the way I remember it is these types of templates "specify" their template arguments.
- generic templates (i.e. less specialized) are picked last.